# Try Catch Exception Helper

Tags: java, spring, performance, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I already made a helper that returns an error message using the **Exception** parameter in another function.(This is an example)

```
void func(int n){ 
    try { 
        // this will throw ArithmeticException if n is 0 
        int x = 10 / n; 
        int y[] = new int[n]; 
        y[x] = 10; 

        // this will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 
        // if the value of x surpasses 
        // the highest index of this array 
        System.out.println("No exception arose"); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println(getErrorType(e)); 
    } 
} 

String getErrorType(Exception e){
    String errorMessage = "";
    if (e instanceof ArithmeticException) 
        errorMessage = "ArithmeticException, Can't divide by 0";
    if (e instanceof ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) 
        errorMessage = "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, This index doesn't exist in this array";
    else
        errorMessage = "error";
    return errorMessage;
}
```

As you can see, I'm using **instanceof** to get the Exception type, and also I can add more info to the String function like the message from the error. Also I can include many error types to this helper.
My question is,

- Is this good to use in Java?
- There are many inconvinients to use it in that way?
- There's another way to implement what I'm trying to do?
- How does it affect performance?

I already know that the good use in try catch blocks is using the specific Exceptions adding catch levels with the specific Exception.But I want to make it generic.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'd want to specify the Exception that you're expecting to happen in try/catch clauses so when other people go through your code, they'll know what exceptions to expect if they ever need to handle them.

You can actually combine your catch clauses into one too, by doing something like this:

```
try { 
    // this will throw ArithmeticException if n is 0 
    int x = 10 / n; 
    int y[] = new int[n]; 
    y[x] = 10; 

    // this will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 
    // if the value of x surpasses 
    // the highest index of this array 
    System.out.println("No exception arose"); 
} 
catch (ArithmeticException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | SomeOtherException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: You're right, that's another way to handle it, but **Exception** contains all of these ExceptionTypes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot of extra work and I can't see the benefit of putting all your exception handling code in a large function. Best practice in Java is to always keep your code modular and leverage off the language as much as possible.

If it's just the detail you want, it's neater to rethrow the exception with a custom message. Here's a trivial example:

```
int divide (int a, int b) {
    try {
        return a / b;
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("Divide by 0", e);
    }
}
```

Remember that you want to handle exceptions differently because you don't want your application to terminate over small things that can be fixed- that isn't good design. If your app runs into a problem that you can recover from, like a bad input from a user, you can catch the exception and stop the crash. Using a generic exception will prevent you from doing this because you won't know what exception was thrown. You could do the handling in your `getErrorType` function but then you might end up with something like:

```
String getErrorType(Exception e){
    String errorMessage = "";
    if (e instanceof ArithmeticException) 
        errorMessage = "ArithmeticException, Can't divide by 0";
        warnUserToChangeValue();
    if (e instanceof IllegalArgumentException) 
        errorMessage = "Bad Argument";
        warnUserToChangeValue();    
    if (e instanceof ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) 
        errorMessage = "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, This index doesn't exist in this array";
    else
        errorMessage = "error";
    return errorMessage;
}
```

This is really hard to read. I'd recommend keeping it simple and just catch according to what you need:

```
catch (ArithmeticException e |  IllegalArgumentException e) 
{
    // The user probably entered a bad value, no reason to terminate, just tell them
    warnUserToChangeValue(); 
}
```

Comment: The idea to use this helper is to return only the error message with the exception type, not including extra logic, as you said, the code is going to be hard to read.
And also the other idea is related to use only Exception param in the catch block.

Comment: Returning an error message with the exception type defeats the purpose of catching an exception. I'd recommend reading this article from the Java tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/advantages.html

Answer (score 0):

Catching **Exception** in general is a bad practice because it will also swallow unrelated bugs like NullPointerException, IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException and other RuntimeExceptions that are BUGS and really should continue propagating.

So the use of:

```
catch (ArithmeticException | SomeOtherException e) {
   ...
}
```

Catching IllegalArgumentException is really bad practice except at the topmost part of your error processing. In which case all you can do is just report it somewhere (like a log).

It's a bug.

An exception to this rule is when you have something like a Thread that should never be interrupted because it's super critical.

In such cases catching Throwable is more effective.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Throw away the whole try/catch block, and have the most top-level method tell the user that you couldn't execute the task he ordered you to do.

**Concept**

That looks like you share a (wide-spread) mis-conception of how to deal with exceptional situations, i.e. "Exceptions are bad! I have to catch them as early as possible!" That's wrong. Exceptions are perfect for telling my caller about my failure: "I couldn't finish my job. You decide if you can do without, retry it some other way, or just signal it to your caller".

Your `func()` has some job to do (whatever that "contract" might be). An exception being thrown out of a method is meant to communicate that this method didn't (fully) do its job.

In your case, a `func()` caller has no chance to find out that the method wasn't able to do anything (thus most probably not fulfilling its contract). So your caller will continue happily, not knowing that a crucial step of his algorithm failed, thus producing either follow-up errors, or even worse: data nonsense.

So, not catching the exception is definitely better, the exception ripples up to your caller, he thus gets informed about the failure and can decide whether he can sensibly continue even after a failure of `func()`.

In most cases, this decision reads "if anything within my algorithm fails, the whole thing fails, and I immediately want to abort all its computation". And that's what you get for free from exceptions if you don't catch anything.

**Your catch clause**

You try to present a user-friendly message describing the problem better than the automatic text form that the Java Runtime associates with the exception.

At a first glance, that seems plausible, but...

If this `func()` is a helper used deep inside your code, the end-user sitting in front of his machine won't find your wording more helpful than the Java texts. Only if you were implementing a desktop calculator where a user explicitly wants to divide two numbers, then an error text talking about division by zero would be helpful to the user. In the typical case, he can't relate that division by zero to anything he wanted from your program (e.g. credit interest calculation).

**Answering your questions**

- Your general approach has some drawbacks, as described above. I doubt that you can create a good, user-sensible error message just from the exception object, independent from the code where it happened. And using "instanceof" in Java is nearly always a bad idea.
- Yes, it's inconvenient. You write lots of lines without a valuable benefit.
- If you really want to stay with the exception-type-dependent texts, use multiple catch clauses for the different exception classes.
- I don't think it makes a relevant performance difference. And your software must be addressing a very strange area if the performance of the error handling matters.